# Highcharts Click Function Not Being Called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, coffeescript

I'm trying to dynamically add a label to the highcharts pie section, but for some reason the click event doesn't seem to be triggering. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong/how to get the console message to log out? Here's the link to the [Highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events) I was following.

```
$('#genderChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
          marginTop: 0,
          marginBottom: 73,
          marginRight: 50,
          plotBackgroundColor: null,
          plotBorderWidth: null,
          plotShadow: false,
          events: {
            click: (e) ->
              console.log "click"
          }
        },
        title: {
          text: '',
          style: {
            fontSize: 10
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
          pointFormat: '<b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
          enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
          pie: {
            size: 300,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
            },
            showInLegend: true
          }
        },
        series: [{
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Gender Breakdown',
          data: [
            {
              name: "Male",
              y: male,
              color: "#9A3334"
            },
            {
              name: "Female",
              y: female,
              color: "#217C7E"
            }
          ]
        }]
      })
```

Comment: `click: (e) ->
              console.log "click"` What is this language ?

Comment: @Brewal [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/)

Comment: It's coffeescript. It's equivalent to

click: function(e) {
  console.log "click";
}

Comment: Ok, I think it would be nice to see it in action. This should work. Are you sure you don't have overlayed divs or something ?

Comment: So I was just playing around and I'm able to get the click event to fire when I click somewhere in the chart div that isn't a part of the actual pie graph

Comment: So basically I'm using the wrong event - I want the event that fires when the pie section is clicked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong event. Use this one :

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.events.click

```
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        size: 300,
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        showInLegend: true,
        events: {
            click: function(e){} // your event
        }
    }
},
```